# Error while installing streamlit in windows 10 using command prompt

Tags: python, cmake, streamlit, pyarrow

```
 -- Running cmake for PyArrow
      cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pwbeeskl\pyarrow_8c168365fb834610b6af613231c7cdc8\build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pyarrow -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe -DPython3_EXECUTABLE=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe -DPYARROW_CXXFLAGS= -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" -DPYARROW_BUILD_CUDA=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_SUBSTRAIT=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_FLIGHT=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_GANDIVA=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_ACERO=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_DATASET=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_ORC=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_PARQUET=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_PARQUET_ENCRYPTION=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_GCS=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_S3=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_HDFS=off -DPYARROW_BUNDLE_ARROW_CPP=off -DPYARROW_BUNDLE_CYTHON_CPP=off -DPYARROW_GENERATE_COVERAGE=off -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=release C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pwbeeskl\pyarrow_8c168365fb834610b6af613231c7cdc8
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
        File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Scripts\cmake.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cmake'
      error: command 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Scripts\\cmake.exe' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
```

Note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

> ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyarrow Failed to build pyarrow

> ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyarrow, which is required to
> install pyproject.toml-based projects

This is the error I got.
I tried to install pyarrow using `pip install` command, that also not working for me.
Then I installed cmake using `pip install`. Still unable to install streamlit for deploying ML project.

Comment: Can you please post the full log from `pip install`. Normally, it should not try to compile pyarrow but rather install the binary wheel.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [i want to install streamlit but geting error in pyarrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63982693/i-want-to-install-streamlit-but-geting-error-in-pyarrow)

Comment: If you're trying to use pyarrow with python3.12 (which seems to be the case), please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77329439/13339621).